# UE4 or Unity or Libgdx for VR project using Oculus rift and Novint falcon

Tags: unity, libgdx, unreal-4, virtual-reality, oculus

I've to make a multiplayer game **Air Hcokey** using 2 Oculus rift and 2 novint falcon controllers , I know that these 3 engines support the Oculus Rift but have no Idea if they do support the [**Novint Falcon**](http://www.novint.com/) , any advice in which one to use in my case ??

Comment: I found a [prototype for Unity here](https://github.com/kbogert/falconunity), but other than that, I think you're best off contacting the game engines' support directly.